# convert std::wstring to const *char in c++

Tags: c++

How can I convert `std::wstring` to `const *char` in C++?

Comment: There's many ways. Which one is right for you depends on a lot of facts you haven't provided. Which encoding do you want to have the result in? What platform/encoding conversion lib are you using?

Comment: Which operating system? At least on Windows you should do this rarely, e.g. if you want to write a UTF-8 string to a file.

Comment: There is this "[Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)", which must be read!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can convert a `std::wstring` to a `const wchar_t *` using the `c_str` member function :

```
std::wstring wStr;
const wchar_t *str = wStr.c_str();
```

However, a conversion to a `const char *` isn't natural : it requires an additional call to [`std::wcstombs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs), like for example:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

std::wstring wStr;
const wchar_t *input = wStr.c_str();

// Count required buffer size (plus one for null-terminator).
size_t size = (wcslen(input) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);
char *buffer = new char[size];

#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
    // wcstombs_s is only guaranteed to be available if __STDC_LIB_EXT1__ is defined
    size_t convertedSize;
    std::wcstombs_s(&convertedSize, buffer, size, input, size);
#else
    std::wcstombs(buffer, input, size);
#endif

/* Use the string stored in "buffer" variable */

// Free allocated memory:
delete buffer;
```

Comment: can you give a full example including wcstombs? I'm trying to solve this the way you suggest.

Comment: when the wstring is wStr:

`const wchar_t *str = wStr.c_str();
    size_t size = wcslen(str) * 2 + 2;
    char * StartPoint = new char[size];
    size_t c_size;
    wcstombs_s(&c_size, StartPoint, size, str, size);`

Comment: @arielhad Why +2 at the end of the size definition? Also, this 'formula' for size assumes that char is 8 bit, and wchar_t is 16 bit, doesn't it? I think it would be better to write it calling sizeof() as it's not necessarily true for all platforms.

Comment: "delete buffer;" : This buffer is an array, so it would be "delete[] buffer;", instead.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this just like that. `std::wstring` represents a string of wide (Unicode) characters, while `char*` in this case is a string of ASCII characters. There has to be a code page conversion from Unicode to ASCII.

To make the conversion you can use standard library functions such as [`wcstombs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw.aspx), or Windows' [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

**Updated** to incorporate information from comments, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Standard library handles this. See `wcrtomb`, `wcsrtombs`, for example.

Comment: @Yossarian: The problem with the standard library's functions is that the standard doesn't define which wide character set, nor does it define which multi byte character set, are used in `wcstombs`. If you need to get the string in a specific encoding (such as UTF-8), then you have to write the conversion yourself, or use a platform specific extension (such as WideCharToMultiByte)

Comment: std::string can contain unicode via UTF-8 and std::wstring is not married to UTF-16/UTF-32. So this this is a very misleading answer.